# MSSQL - substring a value between other values

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
NOIDEHOB_NOIDE1_4321-123
```

i want to create a querie that extract the following values from the example above:

```
NOIDEHOB
NOIDE1
4321-123
```

I need to base the query on the sign `_`. The values `NOIDEHOB`, `NOIDE1` and `4321-123` are dynamic and the length will vary. There will never be any other `_` sign in the string.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string_split()`:

```
select s.value
from string_split('NOIDEHOB_NOIDE1_4321-123', '_') s
```